How to Resolve Protobuf Version Conflict Between Two Dependencies in Android Project?
I am working on an Android project that uses two libraries which depend on different versions of Protobuf. Here are the dependencies:
implementation 'io.livekit:livekit-android:2.5.0' // depends on protobuf 3.22.0
implementation 'org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java:2.8.1' // depends on protobuf 3.10.0

When I use Protobuf version 3.10.0, the org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java library works fine, but the io.livekit:livekit-android library does not work. Conversely, when I use Protobuf version 3.22.0, the io.livekit:livekit-android library works fine, but the org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java library does not work.
I have tried using Gradle's dependency resolution strategies to force a specific version of Protobuf, but it hasn't resolved the issue. Here is what I tried:
configurations {
    configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-javalite', version: '3.10.0'
        }
    }
}

When I use Protobuf 3.10.0 in resolutionStrategy, it works fine for org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java, but it affects the io.livekit:livekit-android module. Conversely, when I use Protobuf 3.22.0, it affects org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java.
Livekit Error:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
21:57:31.586  W     at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.newSchemaForRawMessageInfo(MessageSchema.java:502)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.newSchema(MessageSchema.java:221)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.newSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:85)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.createSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:71)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:93)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.getMessageFieldSchema(MessageSchema.java:4849)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFromHelper(MessageSchema.java:4241)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:3846)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parsePartialFrom(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1531)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parsePartialFrom(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1630)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parseFrom(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1619)
21:57:31.587  W     at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parseFrom(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1612)
21:57:31.587  W     at livekit.LivekitModels$DataPacket.parseFrom(LivekitModels.java:11352)
21:57:31.587  W     at io.livekit.android.room.RTCEngine.onMessage(RTCEngine.kt:970)
21:57:31.587  W     at io.livekit.android.room.RTCEngine$DataChannelObserver.onMessage(RTCEngine.kt:1006)

Whispersystems Error:
Process: com.app.package, PID: 12793
                 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                    at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.newSchemaForRawMessageInfo(MessageSchema.java:507)
                    at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.newSchema(MessageSchema.java:227)
                    at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.newSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:77)
                    at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.createSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:71)
                    at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:90)
                    at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:104)
                    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.makeImmutable(GeneratedMessageLite.java:175)
                    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder.buildPartial(GeneratedMessageLite.java:397)
                    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder.build(GeneratedMessageLite.java:405)
                    at org.whispersystems.libsignal.state.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:46)
                    at org.whispersystems.libsignal.state.SessionRecord.<init>(SessionRecord.java:25)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this conflict or any alternative solutions to use both libraries in my project.

I've no words of encouragement or help I'm afraid. I've had similar in GPB for C++, where Google changed the API of the generated C++ code in some breaking way between versions. There was no option but to adjust my own code to suit. Maybe they've done the same for Java generated code, between 3.10 to 3.22. If they have, that could require you to modify one of your dependencies. That might not be too painful; WhisperSync's github has the .proto files, it could simply be a case of rebuilding the Java source from those using 3.22, and hoping that there's not too many errors / changes to fix up.

It's very difficult to modify a dependency, also whispersystems stopped their support.
